# Theoretically, is the maximum strength of atomic bonds limited to any degree, or is it theoretically infinite?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, material-science

I've been lightly studying to figure out what the absolute peak potential for materials science is, and specifically with the progression of the various strengths, I've come to a bit of a dead end on leads and so I come here again as a last resort.

Is there any theoretical limit to the atomic bond strength of fermionic matter? Or would a sufficiently advanced entity be capable of atomically printing a material, putting the entire energy of The Big Bang into it's atomic bonds so that only The Big Bang could destroy the material?

Also, would this material and it's bond strength be directly correlated with it's density, or could you theoretically craft a material weighing less than a feather yet gluing stars together by the thumb full (metaphorically speaking)?

Thank you again for sharing what would take me potentially AGES to find myself without the knowledge of what words to google and what obscure sources to explore.

Answer (score 3):

The bonding in all "ordinary" (i.e., non-science fiction) materials comes about electrostatically, with the details determined by quantum mechanics. This yields bonding energies of order ~tens of electron volts, max, and there is no way to strengthen those bonds.

FYI the *theoretical* strengths of, say, metals can be calculated on the basis of those effects and the answer is much higher than the actual strengths of metals in practice. This is because all engineering metals contain defects in their crystal structure that provide ductility mechanisms which let the metal yield and deform at stress levels far below the theoretical maximum.

Efforts to improve the strengths of metals are focused on defeating those ductility/deformation mechanisms, but the results (while impressive) are still nowhere near the theoretically-calculated maxima.

Now, if you want bonding energies of order ~tens or hundreds of million electron volts then you have to look instead at how the constituents of *nuclei* are bonded together: the residual effects of the *nuclear force*, which provide what you could call "nuclear glue". The trouble is, we have no methods available with which to form nuclei into wires, bars or other useful shapes; they are so tightly bound together that all nuclei are spherical, or nearly so, and the laws of QM prohibit us from linking protons and neutrons together into such shapes and then staying that way when we let go and step back to admire our handiwork.

Comment: Wow so, just to make sure I'm reading this right, are you saying that through charging the nuclear bonds rather than voltaic bonds is the path to "star-gluing" strong materials, or are you saying that these materials are only possible through making them almost solely out of nuclei, as if it were some kind of metal ore beaten into "rods" and "wires"?